# How to attach a Click handler to a DOM element

Tags: html, extjs, extjs4.2

How do I get a DOM element and attach an event `onClick`?. I tried this code but it does not work:

```
<div>
    <h1 id="some_id">
        click here
    </h1>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
Ext.onReady(function() {
    if(Ext.getDom('some_id'))
    {
        var elDom = Ext.getDom('some_id');

        elDom.on('click', function(){

           Ext.Msg.alert('Status', 'Already get the element from the dom');
        });
    }
    });
```

Fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/2fl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way to do this is to get the `Ext.dom.Element` instead of the actual DOM node. This will allow you to use `.on()`. This is done by using `Ext.get()` instead of `Ext.getDom()`.

```
var elDom = Ext.get('some_id');
if(elDom) {
    elDom.on('click', function() {
        Ext.Msg.alert('Status', 'Already get the element from the dom');
    });
}
```

Comment: Would suggest changing the name, `elDom` doesn't make sense, because it's not referring to the DOM element, but the element wrapper class.

Comment: Agreed, but I was just trying to not change too much, so the important change was more obvious.